# BreezypythonGui program is running but the window is not showing up?

Tags: python, user-interface, anaconda, spyder, breezy

I am just trying to work out some simple programs to get the gist of everything. The program should display a little window that displays "Hello World" but i have come across the problem where my program that uses breezypythongui runs but the window that displays hello world doesn't show up? I tried restarting, updating, and reinstalling anaconda & spyder, but it didn't fix the problem. The program is running in spyder which was downloaded from anaconda. Again, it seems to run with no errors, but the window that displays hello world doesn't show up? I also tryed running it from console  but that didn't work either. The code is bellow, as well as a picture showing the code running...

```
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame

class LabelDemo(EasyFrame):
    
    def __init__(self):
        EasyFrame.__init__(self)
        self.addLabel(text = "Hello World!", row = 0, column = 0)
    
def main():
    LabelDemo().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__name__":
    main()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIilA.png)

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) According to its docs, `breezypythongui` is based on Tkinter. Therefore, to make it work, please go to the menu

`Tools > Preferences > IPython console > Graphics`

and change the `Graphics backend` there to `Tkinter`.

After doing that, please run your code again. It should work without problems.

Comment: where is the menu you are talking about?

Comment: I meant the menus on top of Spyder. Starting from left to right you should the File, Edit, Source menus. Among them is Tools.

Comment: I did what you said but not it just freezes the kernel when i try to run it.

Comment: Ok, please close Spyder and restart it again.

Comment: I restarted spyder several times but now when i run any code that has import breezypythongui or any breezypythongui program it freezes the console like it is waiting for something to happen?  Also if this helps at all, someone else i sent a file to said that if they ran a file i gave with breezy in it, the window didn't show up. And when they copied and paste it the window didn't show up but when they wrote it themself the window showed up...